# Issue subscribing to topic that is populated from libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so

Tags: ros, ros2, plugin, gazebo-ros, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a ray sensor in my Gazebo SDF file. This sensor includes the following plugin defined:

```
    <plugin name="aft_stbd_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
      <ros>
        <!-- Configure namespace and remap to publish to /ray/range -->
        <namespace>/ray</namespace> 
        <remapping>~/out:=range</remapping>
      </ros>

      <output_type>sensor_msgs/Range</output_type>
      <radiation_type>ultrasound</radiation_type>
    </plugin>
```

In my ROS2 node c++ file, i use the following to subscribe to the /ray/range topic:

ray_sub = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Range>(
"ray/range", 1, std::bind(&DVL::setRayData, this, std::placeholders::_1));

I put a simple print statement in the setRayData() function.  When I run my test world with the ray sensor model and my ROS2 node, it never makes it to the setRayData() function.

In a terminal:
*ros2 topic list*
has /ray/range included
*ros2 topic echo /ray/range*
shows the data and it is updating at the appropriate rate

Am I missing something unique that may be needed in the node when using the gazebo_ros sensor plugins available?

FYI: ROS2 Foxy, Gazebo 11

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377045/issue-subscribing-to-topic-that-is-populated-from-libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so/) by [user300](https://answers.ros.org/users/71357/user300/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The queue argument in the create_subscription() needs to be of type rclcpp::SensorDataQoS().  The following works:

ray_sub = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::range>( "ray/range", rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(), std::bind(&DVL::setRayData, this, std::placeholders::_1));

---

Originally posted by [user300](https://answers.ros.org/users/71357/user300/) with karma: 26 on 2021-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosnroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/76716/rosnroll/) on 2021-08-11**:
this was really helpful. thanks